# python - how to add a variable and a number (addition)

Tags: python

how do i add
N4ID which contains 1 to N3ID which also contains it

my code

```
f = open('NID.p','wb')
N2ID = ('1')
pickle.dump(N2ID,f)
f.close()


def add2data():
  f = open('NID.p', 'rb')
  N3ID = pickle.load(f)
  f.close()
  f = open('NID.p','wb')
  N5ID = 1
  N4ID = N3ID + 1
  pickle.dump(N4ID,f)
  f.close()
  print(N4ID)
```

but i get this error

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBWQf.png)

Comment: The error message is very clear: `N3ID` is a string, convert it to integer.

Comment: `N4ID = int(N3ID) + 1`

Comment: thanks @leaf_yakitori i didnt know how to convert them i have not used python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mention you should refer to type casting. In your example you try to add a string with an integer. This is not possible.

You can directly do it by casting `N3ID` to int or you can add some type checks before you proceed with your addition.

In the first case you can simply do `int(N3ID)` and then add your number.

If you want to perform type check there are a couple of ways to do it.

- You can check the type of your var with `type(N3ID)` or `(isinstance(N3ID, int))` and then decide accordingly how to proceed.
- You can check if your var can be cast in integer with `isdigit()` method.

isinstance and type docs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

isdigit is a string method can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdigit#str.isdigit)

Comment: Thanks but I already figured it out my roblox group finder works well now thanks anyway. It is really a good explanation as I just started out